# Order of groups and group elements?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

Let G be a group and let p be a prime. Let g and h be elements of G with order p.

I am wondering how I can use group theory to find the possible orders of the intersection between $\def\subgroup#1{\langle#1\rangle}\subgroup g$ and $\subgroup h$ and also to prove that the number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is a multiple of $p-1$.

I've been looking for the path for ages and got nothing really. These are presented as typical applications to group theory and I'm not at ease with the subject so I'd like to see how you think on this example (in order to get a better idea). Can you hint me? Thank you.

Comment: For the first part, do you know Lagrange's theorem? Do you know that the intersection of two subgroups is a subgroup?

Comment: I know Lagrange's Theorem. Not that the intersection of two subgroups is one but that seems fine to prove from the Subgroup Test, right?

Comment: Yes. That is a basic fact you should certainly try to prove first, before tackling this problem. (It will be useful...)

Comment: Alright, I have proved it now. So now the intersection I'm talking about has clearly maximum order p. But also it is a subgroup of G so its order devides the one of G. hum that doesn't go far enough... I don't see it

Comment: The intersection could have another value besides $p$...

Comment: Oh, yes, that seems like a duplicate, thank you.

Comment: @Timmy I suppose you're implicitly assuming $\;G\;$ is finite, otherwise the number of elements of order some given prime can be infinite...

Comment: Please read tag description before using them. Here *order-theory* is totally inappropriate, and that should be plain to you if you bothered to read its description.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Potato, the first thing to notice is that the intersection of two subgroups, $\langle g\rangle $ and $\langle h\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, but moreover, it is also a subgroup of both $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle h\rangle$. A cyclic group of prime order, such as $\langle g\rangle$ only has two subgroups $\langle 1 \rangle$ and $\langle g\rangle$, so we see that the intersection is either trivial or the two subgroups are the same.

Consider what the above shows about subgroups of order $p$. What can their overlap look like? If you focus on $\langle g\rangle$, how many elements of order $p$ does it have? Can you use these ideas to get what you want?

Comment: Aren't all elements of ⟨g⟩ of order p since p is prime? except e of course. That would mean that ⟨g⟩ has p-1 elements of order p. Now all elements of order p generate a subgroup of G that has order p. These groups are either the same or have only common element e so I'm done, right?

Comment: Yep, pretty much.

Comment: Amazing, I think I got it now! It's not as hard as it seemed then! Thanks